# Update the ion item after each delete in Ionic App

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, multidimensional-array

I have an ionic app where i am saving data in local storage.

Now i am deleting each record from the UI. I am able to delete the each record from localstorage but not able to reflect the page without page refresh.

I used `this.navCtrl.setRoot(this.navCtrl.getActive().component);` but this is removing all previous page functionality like the back button.

Please help suggest where i am doing the mistake.

My home.html looks like below:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of allObj1;let index = index" >
   <ion-item no-lines text-wrap  class="items"  *ngIf='this.allObj1.length > 0'>    
     {{item}} 
       <button ion-button color="orange" (click)="deletereminder(index)" >
          <ion-icon name="trash" item-right ></ion-icon>
       </button>
   </ion-item>
</ng-container>
```

My delete function looks like below:

```
deletereminder(index){
   var newObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Data'));
   var indextodelete = index;
   newObj.data.splice(indextodelete, 1)
   localStorage.setItem('Data', JSON.stringify(newObj));
   var newObj1 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Data'));
// this.navCtrl.setRoot(this.navCtrl.getActive().component);
}
```

Below function is used to retrieve the array from localstorage and display in the UI.

```
/**Start of code for display of saved datafrom localstorage*/
var fullbodyretrievedData = localStorage.getItem("Data");
let fullbodyarray = JSON.parse(fullbodyretrievedData);
if( fullbodyretrievedData !=null){
   this.fullbodylocalstoragelength = fullbodyarray.data.length;
   var fullbodylocalStorageArray = new Array();
   for (var i=0;i<this.fullbodylocalstoragelength;++i){
      fullbodylocalStorageArray[i] = fullbodyarray.data[i];
   }
   var fullbodysortedarray = fullbodylocalStorageArray;
   this.allObj1.push(fullbodysortedarray);
}
else{
   var fullbodysortedarray = [null];
   this.allObj1.push(fullbodysortedarray);
}
/**End of code for display of saved data from localstorage*/
```

My Localstorage array looks like below:

```
Key:   Data
Value: {"data":[[0,"1600452960000"],[1,"1600453020000"]]}
```

Comment: You are displaying your data from `allObj1`.. but after deleting the item from the storage, you are not deleting it from `allObj1`.. this also has to be refreshed with the new data.. Ideally, you should do this `this.allObj1.splice(index,1)` in your `deletereminder`

Comment: i tried using `this.allObj1.splice(index,1)` but not working

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the function below line of code and the issue is resolved now.

```
deletereminder(index){
   this.allObj1[0].splice(index,1) //Add this new line of code to resolve
   var newObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Data'));
   var indextodelete = index;
   newObj.data.splice(indextodelete, 1)
   localStorage.setItem('Data', JSON.stringify(newObj));
   var newObj1 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Data'));
}
```